# How to find if a field with a specific value exist in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am building a application in web but I want to know if is there any way to chech if in a database exist e field with a certain value. 
So for example I want to check if in table `Profile( Profile_Id, User_Id, Address, City...)`
exist the user with User_Id=20. The reason that I want to check this is that if he user exist I want that when I press the button in my form to update the field of the table Profile and if the user do not exist to insert a new row in the table...

For example:

```
If( User_Id exist in table Profile(this is the check statement))

$update_query="update Profile...........

else
$update_query=mysql_query("Insert into Profile..............
```

Please hel me...Thanks in advance

Comment: If you know the field name at design time (and you seemingly do) then you need a simple SQL query that returns a COUNT of rows that match your criteria. If the result is 0 - you do not have matching records.

Comment: but he wants to update existing and insert non existing values :)

Comment: Yes that is what i want

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for

```
INSERT INTO Profiles (user_id,name,age) VALUES (1,"AL","33")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name="Alan", age=34;
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query for this check is:

```
SELECT 1
FROM   Profile
WHERE  User_Id = ?
```

You would replace the `?` with the value being checked (e.g. 20). If you use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), the replacement can be done using [PDOStatement's bindValue method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php).

If the user exists, a result set of one column will be returned. If not, an empty result set will be returned.